# Feed - Спецсимволы в <title>

Tags: дефект, предложение

Если в теме вопроса присутствуют, например, HTML-теги, то, хоть и в фиде они заменены на мнемоники, агрегаторы обрабатывают их как есть, то есть как HTML-теги или вырезают совсем (точно не выяснял).

Возьмём, к примеру, мой недавний вопрос:

> [Как подставить знак плюс «+» в поле <input type=“number”>](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/504087/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%81-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5-input-type-number)

В [фиде](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/504087) мы видим, что угловые скобки в `<title>` заменены на мнемоники.
Однако что мы видим в агрегаторе, по крайней мере в commafeed.com:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Лично я с этим боролся, насколько помню, с помощью двойной замены:

```
< → &lt; → &amp;lt;
> → &gt; → &amp;gt;
...
```

Comment: Что-то сомнительно. Может, агрегатор помучать лучше?

Answer (score 2):

Это баг в вашем аргегаторе RSS.

Обратите внимание на код:

```
<title type="text">
    Как подставить знак плюс &#171;+&#187; в поле &lt;input type=&quot;number&quot;&gt;
</title>
```

Согласно стандарту Atom 1.0, Атрибут `type` на элементе указывает тип содержимого. Значение `"text"` означает, что содержимое — простой текст. Однако ваш агрегатор интерпретирует содержимое как `"html"`, то есть экранированный HTML.

Проблема с неоднозначной интерпретацией содержимого существовала только в старых версиях RSS. Вероятно, поддержку Atom создатели вашего агрегатора прилепили очень криво и просто воспользовались "угадывалкой" для RSS.